# dynamically set background url in CSS for linear gradient

Tags: html, css, angularjs, linear-gradients

I'm trying to have a linear gradient on a carousel I'm putting together and want the background images to be dynamically rendered.  The html portion works great, but in the css, I'm trying to declare a vertical gradient where it becomes black on the bottom.  The syntax I found for this online is that you have to declare the url in the css background, but is there a way to dynamically put in the background url in the css?

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="container">
       <a href="{{::slide.url}}">
          <img ng-src="{{::slide.background}}" style="margin:auto; width:100%;"> 
          <h1><span>{{::slide.name}}</span></h1>
       </a>      
    </div>

.container {
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
  height:50vh;
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, black, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), ***url({{::slide.background}}***);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the URL using `ng-style` based on condition like this (the example with images):

```
<div ng-style="yourCondition === true ? {'background-image':'url(path/to/your/image)'} : {'background-image':'url(path/to/another/image)'}"></div>
```

I didn't test it, but in your case try to do something like this:

```
<div ng-style="'background':'linear-gradient(bottom, black, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), url({{::slide.background}})'"></div>
```

Comment: Plus they'd need to make the gradient go from black to just transparent.

Comment: thanks! i tried your code but added in {}, so it looks like "{ 'background': 'linear-gradient(bottom, black, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), url({{::slide.background}})' }", but it still doesn't work.  the image actually disappears...

Comment: @Dave, try to create two separate elements (an image and a div), and display image under the `div` with gradient